# ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I update the Jupyter notebook from the old version to latest 5.3.1. However, when I try to launch the notebook from anaconda, it throws an import error:
I tried to remove and install Jupyter package, still, the issue persists.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\v-kangsa\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\v-kangsa\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 25, in 
from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
File "C:\Users\v-kangsa\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 27, in 
from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_dir_exists
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'
```

Comment: aha got to update the jupyter_core and jupyter_client. Bad that anaconda navigator won't do it by default. :(

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to update jupyter_core and jupyter_client manually from your terminal:

```
conda update jupyter_core jupyter_client
```

Comment: yep got that working, thanks, I did Jupyter notebook app update from conda navigator, it did to take care of dependency.

Comment: @SantoshKangane Can you please accept my answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

If you've installed jupyter using `pip3`.

```
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter_core jupyter_client
```

Comment: I get "Cannot uninstall 'jupyter-core'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

Answer (score 10):

update jupyter core

```
pip install jupyter-core --upgrade
```

this working for me in Anaconda3 with python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

I've met the same problem when I use  **ipython notebook** .

After I tried upgrade jupyter, then I tried reinstall the ipython.
The import error seem fixed.

> pip3 uninstall  ipython
>
> pip3 install ipython

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to install R the notebook was upgraded to 5.3.1 and same problem appeared, however the highest vote answer apparently didn't work for me.

What I did was:

```
conda uninstall jupyter notebook
```

then:

```
conda install jupyter notebook
```

and the problem solved with the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu after installing RStudio on my system. To solve it, first I tried @MichaelCara suggestion to update jupyter. However, after that I got the following new message error:

*ImportError: libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

which I solved installing *libsodium* [as explained here](https://github.com/bcbio/bcbio-nextgen/issues/2274).

In short:

> conda update jupyter_core jupyter_client jupyter_console
>   conda install libsodium