# Can't start Jupyter Notebook in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It says it installed Jupyter Notebook correctly, but when I launch it I get the error in the image:
[image]

The installation I used was:
pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then Pandas

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

then Jupyter notebook

```
sudo pip3 install Jupyter
```

Does it have anything to do with the version of Python (3 vs 2)?
How do I get Jupyter Notebook to start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure\_dir\_exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists)

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message (so that future users getting a similar  error message may land on your post), thanks

Comment: I can't see the error message - the image is blocked at my work site offshore. Please copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems firing jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 18.4.x

Since jupyter notebook in itself requires another installation we need to install it. So I used this command and it worked please try and see if it works for you

@user-VirtualBox:~$ **sudo apt install jupyter-notebook**

It will ask for any password if you have set for Ubuntu once you enter this you should see

Reading package lists.. Done

Building dependency tree

...

...

etc

Once installation completed, type at prompt

@user-VirtualBox:~$  **jupyter-notebook**

You'll notice that jupyter's notebook system will automatically open Mozilla Firefox and it's ready go.

Let me know how it works.

Thanks