# getting error while opening jupyter notebook.Please assist

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in  from notebook.notebookapp import main File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook__init__.py", line 25, in  from .nbextensions import install_nbextension File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 27, in  from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_dir_exists ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'

Comment: Please describe what you are doing when you get this error. Also, please format the traceback with proper line breaks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure\_dir\_exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists)