# jupyter won't run at all after installing nbextensions

Tags: jupyter-notebook

After trying to install nbextensions jupyter won't run at all now. I get the following message:

```
 File "/Users/briantaylor/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/briantaylor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/Users/briantaylor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 27, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_dir_exists
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'
```

Comment: Are you at least able uninstall nbextensions returning to a usable state? Also what manner did you install? Homebrew?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure\_dir\_exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists)

Comment: Can't really get it back to a usable state. I used conda to install nbextensions.