# Getting Notebooks to recognize conda env ( ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists' )

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

Previously when I launched a jupyter-notebook within a conda environment I would have access to the conda environment. I recently started with a clean Anaconda3 (macOS) install and now I can no longer connect to the conda env with jupyter. The issue seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3242) and this stack-overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists).

As noted in the comments the question is closely related to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook) as well. However [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists) is probably closer and none of the answers in either fix my issue.

I would expect after creating and activating a conda env, that either jupyter notebook:

- would work out of the box and recognize the environment it was
  launched in: this does not happen. the jupyter-notebook doesn't have
  access to the modules installed in the new env
- or, i would need to
  run conda install jupyter in the new environment. the install fails
  with ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'. Note the
  traceback does indeed indicate that it is using the correct conda-env
  /Users/brook/anaconda3/envs/test2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py

I tried the following:

- `conda update jupyter_core jupyter_client` in the base env: this did
  not fix any of the problems
- `conda install jupyter_core jupyter_client`
  notebook in the new env: these installed correctly but then when i
  ran jupyter notebook i got ImportError: cannot import name
  'ensure_dir_exists'
- `conda install nb_conda` in the new env but that
  also failed with ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'
- `conda install nb_conda` in the base env: this almost worked - i think.
  after launching the notebook the conda tab shows my current env as
  the default.

[image]

However when creating a notebook i do not see it listed as an option

[image]

I thought that since its checked as the default the "Python 3" option would be the current env "test3". However this still didn't work - importing modules give ModuleNotFoundError and double checking at the command line the modules are correctly installed.

Finally. I should note that recently I did a Unix install on a cloud instance and running conda install jupyter in the new env worked as expected.

For those who made it this far, some details:

- macOS (10.11.6)
- i tried the graphical-installer, also the cmd line install from the most recent version as well as 5.3.1 and 5.2.0
- and ...

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook). Note, there was a change in Conda that now requires `nb_conda_kernels` installed in the **base** env and `ipykernel` installed in other envs you wish to use in Jupyter.

Comment: @merv Yes thats close. Thanks.  There were a few others too but the question closest to mine in terms of errors thrown is the SO question I listed above. Sadly installing `ipykernel` does not fix anything.  it installs without error, but then `jupyter notebook` gives `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.  installing notebook then works, but then executing `jupyter notebook` gives the `ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'`  error again.  

Note:  I re-ran a Unix install without any issues so I'm guessing this is mac-specific.

Comment: I just noticed that you're trying to launch Jupyter from within the env you want to use. That's not how I use it. I only have Jupyter installed in **base** and I only run `jupyter notebook` from there. Then, all other envs with `ipykernel` are available in Jupyter.

Comment: @merv - I've tried launching from both the base env and the new one.  I'm realizing the SO-question you referenced in your initial comment, wasn't specific to my original question but did address the issue that showed up for me after I installed `nb_conda`.  After installing `ipykernel`  I do now see the conda env listed when creating a notebook.  Sadly however there is a new error - the notebook kernel dies with `ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application'`