# Application Launch Error Jupyter notebook

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed PIP yesterday without knowing that it will affect Jupyter notebook now I have an application launch error whenever I try to open Jupyter notebook. In the past, I installed Jupyter notebook with Anaconda so I use either command or conda prompt to open Jupyter notebook. But now, I cant open Jupyter notebook and I have tried all the methods I know. 
Currently, I have Jupyter notebook 5.0.0. If I update the application or uninstall Anaconda will it work?
I am currently stuck and I don't know how to solve this problem, any suggestions please? The error message is below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\okekec\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\okekec\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in File "c:\users\okekec\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 25, in from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
    File "c:\users\okekec\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 27, in from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_dir_exists
    ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_dir_exists'
```

Comment: Can you post the full error here?

Comment: @JoeA I have edited my question to include the error message, thanks.

Comment: Maybe this command will help you might need to update it: jupyter conda update jupyter_core jupyter_client – Joe A 1 hour ago    Delete

Comment: @JoeA I am now able to launch jupyter but i have another problem. when I run the codes in my jupyter notebook, it is not working. Though I can open the notebook, I cant use it .

Comment: What is the error that shows up when you run it? Try this could work python -m ipykernel install --user also a simlar issue was maybe found here https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10346

Comment: @JoeA I actually figured it out from github, here is the link: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6783 Thanks for helping me with the initial code

Comment: Awesome glad you figured it out and I don't have the rep but for your inital question i believe it is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372019/importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-dir-exists